# Time Complexity of the code snippet

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

[image]

I know the outer while loop runs log(n) times. In the 'for' loop i am having problem. I tried with putting different values of 'n' and then seeing how many times 'for' loop runs , but im not getting a definite answer. For Eg. with n=100 , it runs 13 times, which is neither log(n) nor sqrt(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deduce an expression for $j$ at each iteration from its 
recursive formula.

To do that, notice that at the $l$-th iteration you just add $l$ in the
previous value of $j$. Let $j_l$ be the value of $j$ in the the $l$-th iteration.

Then \begin{align}
j_l&=j_{l-1} + l\\
 j_1 &=1
\end{align}

It is clear now that 
\begin{equation}
j_l = \sum_{i=1}^l i = \frac{l(l+1)}{2}
\end{equation}
where we used [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) to calculate the sum.

Now find the value of $l$ at which the inner loop will finish
\begin{align}
j_l > n\\
\frac{l(l+1)}{2} > n
\end{align}
Finally, we will overestimate $l$ to simplify the procedure. Notice that this overestimation makes no difference assymptotically.

\begin{align} 
l^2 &> 2n\\
l &> \sqrt{2n}
\end{align}

So the overall complexity of this code is $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n}\log n)$.